# Jquery Tools vertical scroll with range input

Tags: jquery, input, range

I am trying to use the Jquery tools range input to scroll up and down a div. I have already implemented it, but its not working correctly.

Here is a link to the page, its on the "portfolio" tab...
http://www.tripl3infinity.com/test/home

My issue is with the range slider and the scrolling div being out of "sync". When the page first loads the slider handle is at the top of the range input, and the div is at the top of it containing wrapper. If I scroll down with the slider, then back up to the top of the range input, there ends up being extra space at the top of the div. If you try it, you will see what I mean.

Here is the script I'm using...

```
$(function() {
//PORT RANGE SLIDER
// get handle to the scrollable DIV
var scroll = $("#portScrollable");
$(":range").rangeinput({ 
// slide the DIV along with the range using jQuery's css() method
onSlide: function(ev, step)  {
scroll.css({bottom: -step});
},
progress: false,
// set prescision
prescision: 0,
// initial value. also sets the DIV's initial scroll position
value: 100,
// this is called when the slider is clicked. we animate the DIV
change: function(e, i) {
scroll.animate({bottom: -i}, "fast");
},
// disable drag handle animation when when slider is clicked
speed: 0
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!